# Un boton que cree y descargue un archivo txt php

Tags: php

Hola estoy haciendo un boton que al dar clic debe crear un archivo txt y descargarlo al mismo tiempo

```
<form method="POST">
    <button class='btn btn-default' style='background-color:white' type="submit" name="Guardar" value="Guardar">Descargar  resultado</button>
  </form>
```

y mi codigo es el siguiente pero no se crea el archivo txt

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
  $archivo='./archivo.txt';
  $file = fopen($archivo, 'ab') ;
  fwrite ($file, $resultado.PHP_EOL);
  fclose($file);
}
```

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Te muestra algún mensaje de error?
En que entorno lo estás ejecutando?

Comment: No me muestra ningún error simplemente no hace nada lo estoy ejecutando de manera local

Comment: Ya lo resolví: era tema de permisos por los que no me dejaba saludos